# AWS Lambda Python error Runtime.ImportModuleError

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a following structure of my directory for Lambda in Python:

```
.
├── lambda_function.py
└── python
    ├── pycache
    ├── bin
    ├── certifi
    ├── certifi-2022.12.7.dist-info
    ├── charset_normalizer
    ├── charset_normalizer-3.1.0.dist-info
    ├── datadog
    ├── datadog-0.45.0.dist-info
    ├── datadog_api_client
    ├── datadog_api_client-2.11.0.dist-info
    ├── dateutil
    ├── idna
    ├── idna-3.4.dist-info
    ├── python_dateutil-2.8.2.dist-info
    ├── requests
    ├── requests-2.28.2.dist-info
    ├── six-1.16.0.dist-info
    ├── six.py
    ├── typing_extensions-4.5.0.dist-info
    ├── typing_extensions.py
    ├── urllib3
    └── urllib3-1.26.15.dist-info
```

For permissions on files I set: chmod 755

I usually archive all the files like that:

```
zip -r9 /path/to/my/root/of/lambda_python/deploy/function.zip .
zip -g function.zip lambda_function.py
```

Here is my import part of code:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import os
import json
import time
from datadog_api_client import ApiClient, Configuration
from datadog_api_client.v1.api.synthetics_api import SyntheticsApi
from datadog_api_client.v1.model.synthetics_trigger_body import SyntheticsTriggerBody
from datadog_api_client.v1.model.synthetics_trigger_test import SyntheticsTriggerTest
```

But I got this error log when trying to test my lambda inside AWS:

```
[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'datadog_api_client'
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Comment: Why not create container lambda? it was specially designed to deal with large and complex dependencies.

Comment: @Marcin because I do not want to use ECR and only to use usual Lambda of it

Comment: Ok, so then why not create lambda layer with your dependencies? Its the second best choice after container lambda.